# woocommerce hook for variation price

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook, price, product-variations

I am trying to modify product price using hooks and have successfully managed to do it for regular product using:

```
function filter_woocommerce_get_price() { 
    return 55; 
}; 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'filter_woocommerce_get_price', 10, 3 );
```

I have noticed that this hook does not apply for variation products, so I found equivalent:

```
function filter_woocommerce_get_variation_price() {
    return 66; 
};
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_variation_price_html', 'filter_woocommerce_get_variation_price', 10, 3 );
```

But it just won't work...
I also tried this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_sale_price_html', 'my_html', 10, 2);
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_price_html', 'my_html', 10, 2);
function my_html( $price, $variation ) {
    return woocommerce_price(5);
}
```

And similar solutions I found online, but nothing changed my variation product price.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I will try a little later to find something convenient and tested, as I am a little busy now. Variable products prices and variations prices are really much more complicated, than all other products types… [**helgatheviking**](http://stackoverflow.com/users/383847/helgatheviking) user is the expert here in SO, concerning that kind of issues.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.
What I'm doing with regular prices is switching them with a custom field value if a certain user role is logged in. The same thing I need is for variation product prices.

I know variations can have range of prices so it is difficult to do the same, but in my case, if a product comes in different colors, price will stay the same so all need is to pull that same custom field value instead of variation price.

this is the link to dev site: http://bajko.webdotagency.com/
but it's in serbian...

thanks again

Comment: Thanks for that important details *(No doubt that Topalovic was serbian :) …)* — If you don't know (and want it), you can delete some old un-useful comments clicking on the little greyed cross icon when hovering them…

Comment: Will do, if it gets crowded... hope this isn't subtle suggestion because i wrote something inappropriate :)
I really appreciate you taking time to look at it when you get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not defining the required arguments for your function, the number **3** add the end of `add_filters` means that you are passing 3 arguments, so you have to do it like this:

```
function filter_woocommerce_get_variation_price($price, $product) { 
    return 66; 
}; 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_variation_price', 'filter_woocommerce_get_variation_price', 10, 2 );
```

So the function can be called.

Comment: Hi, thank's for an answer, but you posted hook for woocommerce_get_price, this I managed to get to work with and without arguments. It's the woocommerce_get_variation_price that I'm having troubles with.
I tried adding argument's to that hook as well, but still no luck.

Comment: Hi, I updated the answer to use `woocommerce_get_variation_price` if it works, select as answer, You have to change the add_filter call